# You have security/openssl installed but do not have DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl set in your make.conf

Tags: freebsd, openssl, bsd-ports

On FreeBSD, ever since I installed `openssl` explicitly I have the following message when I install most ports that require `openssl`:

```
/!\ WARNING /!\
You have security/openssl installed but do not have DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl set in your make.conf
```

As I'm fairly new to FreeBSD, I would like to know what's the meaning of the message and how I can adopt my configs to get rid of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run `echo 'DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl' >> /etc/make.conf` (as root) if you really have installed security/openssl.

---

For users of an other port than security/openssl:

- for security/openssl-devel: `echo 'DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl-devel' >> /etc/make.conf`
- for security/libressl: `echo 'DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=libressl' >> /etc/make.conf`
- for security/libressl-devel: `echo 'DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=libressl-devel' >> /etc/make.conf`

To use/link openssl from your system (world): `DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=base` (default without installing any libressl* or openssl* port).

---

If you get the following error:

> You have a /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so file installed, but the framework is unable
>    to determine what port it comes from.
>   Add DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl= to your /etc/make.conf and try again.

And you don't know or can't remember which one you have installed, check the output of `pkg info -ox "openssl|libressl"`, for example, to determine how to define `ssl` as `DEFAULT_VERSIONS`.

Note: OpenSSL implementation, using ports (not packages), can be switched at any time but:

1. make sure programs that rely on it are compatible (few months ago, a port - I can't remember which one - was marked incompatible with libressl)
2. each port which depends on it have to be rebuild (eg to switch from openssl to libressl: `portmaster -o libressl openssl && portmaster -r libressl` should do the trick)

Comment: Could elaborate about the logic behind? Do I get it right, if this tells all future port-builds to use the openssl port I installed? Instead of whatever might have been installed already?

Comment: You can't install, throught ports, two different OpenSSL implementations. This tells 1) if ports have to be linked to openssl part of your system (/usr/lib/lib{crypto,ssl}.so) or, a newer one, you may have installed via ports (/usr/local/lib/lib{crypto,ssl,tls}.so) ; 2) FreeBSD needs this to handle ports dependencies since this gives you the choice of the OpenSSL implementation you want to use.